# convert modulus in public key to base64 format problem

Tags: c++, openssl, base64, rsa

I have a public key (RSA) like below

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsV60NX4NguP4PYvwxL+5
W+bNqYsFXvMBXuwEYKZr44BvNc0cNEi4Wo3q3MxHiwqkM4Jgik8ZeZrcF0kxHpBO
TIqMltC02xomm2jVPhE5l+Qba/u1NnzZBswKyvfG8ctm3cG3vbyNIb2h8bLhV9YB
wGgaBo9uGdCK6tnRygxYbPe73GhASunkDJKK4tgcdSbXWQLIFcMGFQk3Wplo2AW/
Z9bn5KfrWgB5Tzm/JHON92bO8HXyVFvkJqUwMzMP2s+IlUUbHWYumH6Dg9kRvI9u
k8xnPWqMxTXnrvL2+tc8eeEyB0aFKg0BgZYn+v7VNrbFMjJWF8eZerY/TSL4DRxF
FwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I want n(modulus) in base64 format
when I use an online tool I receive:

```
"n":"sV60NX4NguP4PYvwxL-5W-bNqYsFXvMBXuwEYKZr44BvNc0cNEi4Wo3q3MxHiwqkM4Jgik8ZeZrcF0kxHpBOTIqMltC02xomm2jVPhE5l-Qba_u1NnzZBswKyvfG8ctm3cG3vbyNIb2h8bLhV9YBwGgaBo9uGdCK6tnRygxYbPe73GhASunkDJKK4tgcdSbXWQLIFcMGFQk3Wplo2AW_Z9bn5KfrWgB5Tzm_JHON92bO8HXyVFvkJqUwMzMP2s-IlUUbHWYumH6Dg9kRvI9uk8xnPWqMxTXnrvL2-tc8eeEyB0aFKg0BgZYn-v7VNrbFMjJWF8eZerY_TSL4DRxFFw"
```

but when I use openssl in my c++ code result is different:
"n":"sV60NX4NguP4PYvwxL+5W+bNqYsFXvMBXuwEYKZr44BvNc0cNEi4Wo3q3MxHiwqkM4Jgik8ZeZrcF0kxHpBOTIqMltC02xomm2jVPhE5l+Qba/u1NnzZBswKyvfG8ctm3cG3vbyNIb2h8bLhV9YBwGgaBo9uGdCK6tnRygxYbPe73GhASunkDJKK4tgcdSbXWQLIFcMGFQk3Wplo2AW/Z9bn5KfrWgB5Tzm/JHON92bO8HXyVFvkJqUwMzMP2s+IlUUbHWYumH6Dg9kRvI9uk8xnPWqMxTXnrvL2+tc8eeEyB0aFKg0BgZYn+v7VNrbFMjJWF8eZerY/TSL4DRxFFw=="

My code:

```
 string JSONWebKey::GetPublicKeyNBase64(RSA* key)
 {
    int public_exponent, modulus;
    RSA_get0_key(key, &n, &e, NULL);
    public_exponent = BN_get_word(e);
    modulus = BN_num_bits(n);
    if (public_exponent != 3 && public_exponent != 65537)
    {
        //("WARNING: Public exponent should be 3 or 65537 but is:" + to_string(public_exponent));
        return "";
    }
    if (modulus != 1024 && modulus != 2048 && modulus != 3072 && modulus != 4096 && modulus != 8192)
    {
        //("ERROR: Unknown modulus length =" + to_string(modulus));
        return "";
    }
 
    unsigned char * buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc((BN_num_bytes(n) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    buffer[BN_num_bytes(n)] = '\0';
    int len = BN_bn2bin(n, buffer);
    base64(buffer, len);
 
    return buffer;
 }
 
  
 
 static string base64(const unsigned char *input, int length)
 {    
    BIO *bmem, *b64;
    BUF_MEM *bptr;
 
    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);
    BIO_write(b64, input, length);
    BIO_flush(b64);
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);
 
    char *buff = (char *)malloc(bptr->length);
    memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length - 1);
    buff[bptr->length - 1] = 0;
 
    BIO_free_all(b64);
 
    return buff;
 }
```

what's wrong and how can I get the same result as from online tools?
I use this base64 n in JWS(JSON Web Signature)

Comment: Not an answer, but both your functions leak memory. Every call to `malloc` must be followed by a call to `free`.

Comment: this is sample code not all of it - why online tool result is different with my code result ? ( "n":"sV60NX4NguP4PYvwxL-5W- ... <> "n":"sV60NX4NguP4PYvwxL+5W+ )

Comment: So, basically OpenSSL seems to use the standard Base64 encoding, while the online tool seems to use the so-called Base64URL encoding, see [Bade64 variants on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history), is this the only difference you observe?

Comment: thank you how can i get Base64URL encoding in openssl ?

Comment: replace '-' with '+' and '_' with '/' is enough ?

Comment: Uh, add `=` signs until the result has a length of base64 characters which is a multiple of 4. Wrong direction, sorry.